# Writing/applying "subtract the mean"-function to standardize regression parameters

Tags: r, function, parameters, regression, centering

I was trying to write and apply a seemingly easy function that would standardize my continuous regression parameters/ predictors. The reason is that I want to deal with multicollinearity.

So instead of writing `x-mean(x,na.rm=T)` each time, I'm looking for something more handy which does the job for me - not least because I wanted to exercize writing functions in R. ;)

So here is what I tried:

```
fun <- function(data.frame, x){
data.frame$x - mean(data.frame$x, na.rm=T)
}
```

Apparently this is not too wrong. At least it doesn't return an error message.

However, applying `fun` to, say, the built-in `mtcars` dataset and, say, the variable `disp` yields this error message:

```
#Loading the data:
 data("mtcars")

fun(mtcars,x=disp) #I tried several ways, e.g. w and w/o "mtcars" in front

Warning message:
 In mean.default(mtcars$x, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My guess is that it is about how I applied the function, because when I do manually what the function is supposed to do, it works perfectly.

Also, I was looking for similar questions on writing and applying such a function (also beyond the Stack Exchange universe), but I didn't find anything helpful.

Hope I didn't make a blunder due to my novice R-skills.

Comment: Use `data.frame[[x]] - mean(data.frame[[x]], na.rm=T)` where x is a string: `fun(mtcars,x="disp")`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a function in R which does what you want to do: `scale()`. 
You can just write `scale(mtcars$hp, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)` which then subtracts the mean of the vector from the vector itself.

In combination with apply this is powerful; You can, for example center every column of your dataframe by writing:

```
apply(dataframe, MARGIN = 2, FUN = scale, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
```

Before you do that you have to make sure that this is a valid function for your column. You cannot scale factors or characters, for example.

In regards to your question: Your function should have to look like this:

```
fun <- function(data.frame, x){
  data.frame[[x]] - mean(data.frame[[x]], na.rm=T)
}
```

and then when specifying the function you would have to write `fun(mtcars, "hp")` and specify the variable name in quotation marks. This is because of the special way the `$` operator works, you cannot use a character string after it.

Comment: Thanks. Answer accepted and upvoted. ;)

But could you elaborate a little more on why `data.frame$x` --> `mtcars$disp` wouldn't work so I can wrap my head around this?

Also and just out of curiosity, would there be a way to make a function dataset-specific, so that you only have to write `fun(x)` or `fun("x")`? I tried to make the function specific for my dataset, but it didn't work. Of course, now that I have `scale()` I don't need this any more.

Comment: The problem rests in the `$` operator, which does not accept strings. There are multiple ways to subset a dataframe, the most prominent ones are: `df$var` and df[["var"]]. The second one does accept character strings, while the first one does not. So we have to use the second one if we want to subset via a character string. Making a function dataset specific is not something you want to do, because it does not save any code-writing.